# Manually Install Windows Updates?

Tags: windows, macos, windows-update, bootcamp

I was wondering if there is a way that a Windows update could be installed manually without the use of Windows Update(the update file is extracted and placed into correct file locations). I am looking into a way for Mac users to keep their Bootcamp version of Windows updated all the time without needing to be booted into Windows for updates to occur. Is this some sort of possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to download and update windows manually

"All that is left to do then is to double-click on the downloaded MSU file to install the update."

article here -> https://www.ghacks.net/2019/07/30/how-to-download-and-install-windows-updates-manually/https://www.ghacks.net/2019/07/30/how-to-download-and-install-windows-updates-manually/

But keep in mind you will probably need reboot any way...